# algorithm to compare coordinate paths

Tags: algorithm, gps, coordinates, cluster-analysis

I'm working on a project that is working with paths in 2 dimensional space. The paths are lists of coordinate pairs (x,y) that trace out a route a user has taken, for instance the path of a mouse on the screen for some fixed time, say 5 seconds. I'm looking for a way to group the paths by some measure of "sameness." Are there any algorithms that are designed for this? For instance, if the start position and end position of two paths is similar, and they both travel in some "channel" across the page in some way.

Comment: what do you mean by sameness ?

Comment: How about comparing the angles between consecutive legs (lines between two coordinate pairs). This way paths may be similar which go in different directions but having the same "shape". Another possibility would be comparing the angles of each line segment (leg) and a reference axis, e.g. screen x-axis in your axample.

Comment: I did some thinking, and I came up with this: imagine the coordinate space as square cells (say 10 by 10). Then map (x,y) coordinates to the cell they are in. Assign a letter to each cell. Run the levenstein edit distance algorithm on the strings, using custom weights for letter substitutions that reflect the distance b/w cells. This should yield a cost for converting one path to another.

Comment: The idea of grid cells id good, but I wouldn't use the Levenshtein distance; words are rather exact compared to mouse paths. I'd draw each path on the coarse grid with a simple algorithm, Bresenham perhaps. Each path is reduced to a set of grid cells. When you compare two paths, compare their sets `A` and `B`. If the sets are disjoint, the paths differ; if they are identical, they match ideally. You could then probably calculate a match quality between 0 and 1 as `|A ∩ B| / |A ∪ B|`, i.e. the number of elements in the intersection of the sets divided by the number of elements in their union.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **time series similarity measures**, such as DTW and SAX.

see also: [Dynamic Time Warping on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping). This technique can in particular be used with geodetic distance between coordinate pairs as "inner" distance function.